# Why is this div in the modal not stretching vertically?

Tags: css

does anyone know why the div inside the modal does not stretch vertically but the one on the page does?

[Here is a demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/colorbox-resize/)

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    display:none;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.left` expands to the size of its content, since there is no `height:` defined. There is less content in the boxed version, so the DIV is shorter.

Comment: Oh my god! I forgot the file was loaded externally and there was another div. Thanks Diodeus :)